# How can I disable the virtual keyboard for all my WPF apps?

Tags: c#, wpf, virtual-keyboard

I saw method to do this for current control but I need to do it for all app. I have touch scren and when i click on some textbox virtual keyboard from windows 7 shown. I don't need it because i how own keyboard in program.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you disable the virtual keyboard for the entire OS? or do you want the virtual keyboard to be displayed when you're not using your application?

Comment: I want to disable virtual keyboad from Windows 7 in my application

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got an answer in the few months the question was online, but this worked for me.

First, you need a reference to Microsoft.Ink.dll.

```
var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
TextInputPanel panel = new TextInputPanel(handle);
panel.InPlaceVisibleOnFocus = false;
```

That first line gets a Handle to the window of your app, and then you just need to create the TextInputPanel object and set it's InPlaceVisibleFocus to false. This will no longer show the TIP icon when a textbox is touched.

Comment: That works for .NET Framework 3.5. What about .NET 4.5?